# Foxit PDF, accidentally selected document to open in full screen, how to reverse?

Tags: pdf, foxit-reader

I have a PDF document that upon opening, requested to go into full-screen.
I then accidentally said yes to that request and now every time the file opens, it defaults to a full screen.

Is there any way to reverse this request and make it not default to opening in a full-screen mode?

My settings from `Preferences -> Documents` are to have a "Normal" display.

Comment: Does [How to View/Change Initial View of a PDF](https://kb.foxit.com/hc/en-us/articles/360046423852-How-to-View-Change-Initial-View-of-a-PDF) help?

Comment: Didn't seem to be an option for me; I went to File -> Properties and didn't see "Initial View" as any option.

Comment: Hmmm, if you make a copy of the file and open that, do you get the full-screen request again?

Comment: @AndrewMorton If I make a copy of that file, and then rename it, then yes, I get the full-screen request again. However, if I rename the file back to its original name, the PDF will default again into a full-screen mode.  // At least that's a workable alternative for now, thanks.

Comment: Try in *Preferences > History* to uncheck "Restore last view settings when reopening".

Comment: @KJ & harrymc // I tried both, and (1) "Restore last view settings when reopening" didn't work; and (2) any other settings under the search of the "restore" term in the preferences didn't work either.

Comment: @KJ Yes, I've tried that too by closing Foxit entirely, removing all processes related to Foxit, and reopening; It didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, what worked for me was making a copy of the file, renaming it, then opening the file again, being careful not to allow it to default to a full-screen.

This is probably a software bug that could be addressed later, but I will assume for now that such a work-around would universally valid across all versions of Foxit readers, in the event that I am not able to update the software.